# How do you use "name" attribute in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

###### My Environment

TypeScript
ReactJS

###### The error I am receiving when attempting to use **name** as an attribute.

> Type '{ name: string; "data-id": string; "data-type": string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.
> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'

##### My current code that is throwing the error:

`<div name="termly-embed" data-id="**************************" data-type="iframe"></div>`

Comment: [This reads like an XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to give a `div` element a `name` in the first place? You should probably be using something else (like an `id` or ref instead).

Comment: I am running into this exact same problem with integrating Termly into an react app, did you ever find a workaround? ID doesn't work, neither does data-name.

Comment: I used a package that pushes the script into the Head tag upon building. After wrapping the script in the package's jsx element tags it basically treats it like a string, so it will permit any syntax.

Comment: Another way around this is to extend the component class and add the name props.

Comment: Can you expand on how you were able to get this to work? Also running into this issue with Termly and a Typescript React site.

Comment: I got around with this by using jsx page for privacy policy and terms of use. I didnt want to add more complexity to this by sticking to typescript for these pages. For those who are talking about XY Problem the main issue is that termly wants you to use div element with name attribute otherwise their script tag is not able to render the page properly. May be this should be handled by Termly in a better way for typescript pages.

Comment: Any solution ^for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since name property does not exist, it is custom so you can use `data-` attributes. Try to change it with `data-name`

```
<div data-name="termly-embed" data-id="**************************" data-type="iframe"></div>
```